# Loop through TextBoxes to confirm all information has been entered

Tags: vba, excel-2013

I have looked through numerous loop posts on here and unfortunately, I have been unable to modify what I have found to serve my needs, so I am asking for some help.

Please note I am still relatively new to loops as you can see by my other posts.

Long and short of my problem is I need to run a check on TextBox controls with a Tag value of "Required" in three different Frames that are all on the same UserForm to make sure they are completed when the user tries to enter a value in a TextBox on that same UserForm.  If any of the TextBoxes with the Tag of "Required" have no value then I need a debug print to show me the names of those TextBoxes.  From there I will be able to figure out how to add the print output to a msgbox.  Below is the code I have started, but I am stuck on how to store each of the TextBoxes that have no value in a variable that I can use for the debug print.

```
Private Sub yLPLendComp_Enter()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim i As Integer

'   SET THIS TO STORE THE CTRL.NAME IF BLANK??
    i = 0

'   THIS LOOKS THROUGH EACH REQUIRED TEXTBOX (SET BY TAG VALUE)
    For Each ctrl In LP.LoanInfo.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            If ctrl.Tag = "Required" And ctrl.Value = "" Then
                i = i + 1
                Debug.Print ctrl.Name
        End If
    Next ctrl
'   IF THE VALUES ARE BLANK THEN MSG BOX APPEARS AND PRINTS THE EMPTY TEXT BOX NAMES
'    If i = 1 Then
'        Debug.Print ctrl.Name
'        MsgBox "Not all fields that need to be completed are complete please complete your required fields.", vbCritical, UCase("error")
'    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you could just add the control names to a collection object.

Comment: Your `i` variable isn't doing anything here. This doesn't solve your problem though.

Comment: Does `Debug.Print ctrl.Name` not print the name of a required control without any entry? It certainly looks like it should. Or is that not your current problem?

Comment: You're missing an `End If`.

Comment: @ArcherBird im not familiar at all with a collection object; would you be able to provide an example of what you are thinking for me?  @urdearboy I removed the `i` variable.  @Comintern thanks for point that out I totally missed that missing `End If`.

Comment: I actually built a whole module that uses tags to confirm if a control has the proper information in it. it includes a validate and a save function, plus a couple other things. it assumes access though, so if you are doing a form in excel it wouldnt work. But since you have an answer, im going to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub yLPLendComp_Enter()

    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim msg As String, sep

    For Each ctrl In LP.LoanInfo.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            If ctrl.Tag = "Required" And ctrl.Value = "" Then
                msg = msg & sep & ctrl.Name
                sep = vbLf
            End if
        End If
    Next ctrl

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "One or more required fields need to be completed" & vbLf & msg, _
                 vbCritical, "Missing Information"
    End If
End Sub
```

If your control names aren't user-friendly, you could use `Tag` values like "Required:User Friendly Name Here" then check for

```
If ctrl.Tag Like "Required:*"
```

and then

```
msg = msg & sep & Replace(ctrl.Tag, "Required:","")
```

**EDIT**: to use text from your linked labels

```
msg = msg & sep & Me.Controls("Label_" & ctrl.Name).Caption
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help again Tim.  It is really appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if I should start a new thread for this or if i can just add a follow up question to this?  Where would I start if i wanted the `msgbox` to display the label caption of the TextBox that is blank?

Comment: I guess that would depend on how the label is linked to the textbox, since they're separate controls.

Comment: i linked the label name to the textbox name by just adding the TextBox name after Label_
example: Label name = Label_ApprovedBy and the corresponding TexBox name is ApprovedBy.